# How to execute a Laravel console command in a controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have custom console command in Laravel. How can I run it single time from controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can call artisan command by doing something like

```
Artisan::call("my:command", ['param1' => $variable, '--otherparam' => 'value']);
```